# Flutter how to have multiple Lists

Tags: flutter, dart

i am beginner in flutter , i created a widget that displays a player informations , i used ListView and ListView.builder but i had an uknown error that said : Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize' and Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.

i do not know what is the source of this error , it started only when i added the ListView builder , before i add it everything was working fine

here what i have tried:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tl_fantasy/widgets/Player_Widget.dart';
import 'player_arguments.dart';

class PlayerDetails extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final PlayerArguments args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    List<Stats> stats = [
      Stats("Matches", args.matches ),
      Stats("Goals", args.goals ),
      Stats("Assists", args.assists ),
      Stats("Saves", args.saves ),
    ];

    List<Team> teams = [
      Team("Barcelona B", "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ef/9c/3f/ef9c3fccec423f70376fcafa05c5d447.jpg","1998" ),
      Team("Barcelona", "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ef/9c/3f/ef9c3fccec423f70376fcafa05c5d447.jpg","2005" ),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Player Details"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[300],
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                end: Alignment.centerRight,
                colors: [Colors.purple, Colors.blue])
        ),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                  end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  colors: [Colors.purple, Colors.black38])),
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                child:    Card(
                  elevation: 4.0,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child:
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(args.image),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width:10.0),
                        Spacer(),
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: <Widget> [
                            Text(args.name, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                            )),
                            const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                            Text(args.club, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                            )),
                            const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                            Text("Role : "+args.role, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.grey[600],
                            )),
                            const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                            Text("Position : "+args.club, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.grey[600],
                            )),
                            const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                            Text("Nationality : "+args.nationality, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.grey[600],
                            )),

                          ],
                        ),

                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: stats.length,
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 4.0
                    ),
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                      return Card(
                        child: Center(
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 0),
                                  child:  Text(stats[index].result,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                  child: Text(stats[index].title,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0)),),

                              ]
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  )
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
             Container(child:
             ListView.builder(
               itemBuilder: (context, index){
                 return Card(
                   elevation: 4.0,
                   shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                   ),
                   child: Padding(
                     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                     child:
                     Row(
                       children: <Widget>[
                         CircleAvatar(
                           backgroundImage: NetworkImage(teams[index].image),
                         ),
                         const SizedBox(width:10.0),
                         Spacer(),
                         Column(
                           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                           children: <Widget> [
                             Text(teams[index].name, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                               fontSize: 18.0,
                             )),
                             const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                             Text("joined : "+teams[index].date, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                               fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.grey[600],
                             )),
                           ],
                         ),

                       ],
                     ),
                   ),
                 );
               },
               itemCount: teams.length,
             ),),
            ],
          ),
        ),

      ),
    );
  }
}


class Stats{

  String title;
  String result;

  Stats(this.title,this.result);

}

class Team {

  String name;
  String image;
  String date;

  Team(this.name,this.image,this.date);

}
```

I am trying to know what happened and how to solve the error after i added the ListView.builder

Comment: Try adding shrinkWrap: true in your ListView.builder

Comment: oww it works thank you , the problem the screen has a lot of scrollable elements , how to make it with better scrolling while keeping the listviews?

Comment: You can set the primary: false for all the inner scrollviews so that only the parent scrollview is primary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
Container(child:
ListView.builder(
itemBuilder: (context, index){
return Card(
```

to this:

```
Flexible(child:
ListView.builder(
shrinkwrap: true,
itemBuilder: (context, index){
return Card(
```

This is caused because you're using a listviewbuilder inside a column, and both expand in the same direction, flutter doesn't know when to stop laying out the listview. If Flexible doesn't work, use expanded instead, and keep the shrink wrap.

Comment: oww it works thank you , the problem the screen has a lot of scrollable elements , how to make it with better scrolling while keeping the listviews?

Comment: You're most welcome @FaresBenSlama , kindly mark it as the answer to your question and upvote this comment if it's helpful, I'd appreciate it. Regarding your second question, you should use the property of `physics: NeverScrollabePhysics()` inside your listviews. This will stop them from scrolling. But you still want your whole page to scroll, so wrap your column inside a SingleChildScrollView. It should solve your problems. Happy coding.

Comment: i am sorry i tried to do it but i could not , it is my first week of using flutter and i am still unable to understand what i should change to apply your answer about the second question

Comment: It's okay, just be sure to read the documentation and understand everything you learn new. Inside Listview builder, under `shrinkwrap: true`, you can add `physics: NeverScrollabePhysics()`

Comment: this is not the problem , my problem is about the next step

Comment: what do you mean by "better scrolling"?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [CustomScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html) with [SliverList](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverList-class.html) and/or [SliverGrid](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverGrid-class.html) for multiple scrolling list in the same widget.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `shrinkWrap: true` inside `listView.builder`

**--UPDATE--**

You can disable the scroll of the child scrollable widget if its parent is already scrollable.

```
children: [
    ListView.builder( 
         ...
         physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
         ...
       )
    ...
```

Comment: oww it works thank you , the problem the screen has a lot of scrollable elements , how to make it with better scrolling while keeping the listviews?